# Magento custom module - saving products

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

This is something that has challenged me for a few days now and I am getting rather frustrated with searching for help/solutions - so trusty StackOverflow it is!

I have made a custom module with a custom database in Magento 1.7 (contains a few things like title, content) for basically a custom static block. I have implemented the product selector available [here](https://github.com/andrei-tara/magento-product-selector).

Although - this just does the actual product selecting - no saving functionality!

I am very stuck on how to save the selected magento products - what is the correct/best way?

I thought either comma separated IDs/SKUs for simplicity - or should I create a new entity type? Any knowledge/guidance on the latter would be hugely helpful - specifically saving a product of a new entity type.

Would the code to save the products go in `<Module>/controllers/Adminhtml/<Module>Controller.php -> saveAction()` or elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `<Module>/controllers/Adminhtml/<Module>Controller.php`

```
public function saveAction()
{
    if ( $this->getRequest()->getPost() ) {
        try {
            $postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();


            Mage::getModel('productsselector/productsselector')->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))
                ->setProductSku($postData['product_sku'])
                ...
                ->save();



            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item was successfully saved'));
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setProductsselectorData(false);

            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setLocalshipData($this->getRequest()->getPost());
            $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
            return;
        }
    }
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
}
```

Read more @ [Custom Module with Custom Database Table](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table)